# Remove dotted line under button

Tags: html, button, href

I have a image button in my nav bar but I'd really like to remove the dotted line under the link.

[image]

The left arrow is the button which contains the link and as you can see under it tis dotted line appears.

This is the code for adding the navbar and button:

```
<div id="navbar"> <a href="reList/holder.html"><img src="images/bk.png" alt="Index"/></a>
```

I've tried:

```
<div id="navbar"> <a href="HB/suit.html"><img src="images/bk.png" alt="Index" onfocus="if(this.blur)this.blur()"/></a>
```

But it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I think something visual is required. What do you mean by "dotted" line? Is it the underlining that a browser will do to a hyperlinked element?

Comment: Apologise for me being unclear. I'ved added an image of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the limited information in the question, I'd suggest that you might be looking for:

```
#navbar :focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

This selector will style all elements that are focused by the user that are descendants of the element with the id of `navbar`.

Bear in mind that it's better not to simply remove the outline, but offer an alternative styling to give those users that use the <kbd>tab</kbd> button to navigate a visual indication of where they are on the page.

For example:

```
#navbar :focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #ffa;
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick. I've edited my post and added an image to show you what I'm wanting to remove. This website will only be accessed from a mobile device, so if we could remove the outline completely that would be great.

Comment: Can you reproduce a small ("[mcve]") demonstration of the code? With only enough to replicate the problem (nothing extra), ideally as a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that would allow me to reproduce the problem on my own mobile devices?

Comment: Interesting, I created a JS Fiddle, but the problem doesn't seem to appear there. Seems that the problem lies deeper within the code so I'll have to look deeper into it. Many thanks for trying to help me though.